# How to make A column of spreadsheet display the name of the month, which index is the row?

Tags: google-sheets-api, bug-reporting

Create an empty google spreadsheets. Enter following

```
=ROW()      =MONTH(A1)
=ROW()      =MONTH(A2)
=ROW()      =MONTH(A3)
=ROW()      =MONTH(A5)
```

output:

```
1   -January-
2   -December-
3   -December-
4   -December-
5   -December-
6   -December-
7   -December-
8   -December-
9   -December-
10  -December-
11  -December-
12  -December-
```

Is there a workaround?

Seems like a ridicolous bug/intentional bad design choice in Google Spreadsheets

Naturally,       `=MONTH(=ROW())` does not work correctly either

Answer (score 0):

```
1/1/2021    -January-
2/1/2021    -February-
3/1/2021    -March-
4/1/2021    -April-
5/1/2021    -May-
6/1/2021    -June-
7/1/2021    -July-
8/1/2021    -August-
9/1/2021    -September-
10/1/2021   -October-
11/1/2021   -November-
12/1/2021   -December-
```

solution is formatting. first, format first row and put validation as a date. then, format second row as a date (month only, verbal). then enter first two dates. then autofill the rest of date by selecting first two and grabbing the corner of the selection (autofill `A` column)

then enter `=A1` to `B1`, and autofill `B` column too